# JavaScript html editing error

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to JS, just writing some scripts to learn. Could someone show me where I'm going wrong here? I think it may just be a syntax error somewhere or that I haven't used the correct features for this task.

Thanks :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript &#8226; training</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id='textOff'>
        Hi there this is some sample text for my JS
    </div>
    <input type='submit' value='show me some stuff!' onclick='show();'/>
    <script>
    function show() {
        var text = document.getElementByID('textOff');
        console.log(text); //debugging
        text.id = 'mainText';
    };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #17161F;
    color: white;
}

#mainText {
    width: 20%;
    height: 30%;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 20%;
}

#textOff {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Well, what should be happening and doesn't happen?

Comment: You might not noticing anything because 1: See answer below about case sensitivity and 2: You are changing the elements 'id'.

Comment: check your typo :

correct syntax is "getElementById".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

```
 getElementById // correct
 getElementByID // incorrect
```

Use the JavaScript console provided by your browser:

> TypeError: Object `#<HTMLDocument>` has no method '`getElementByID`'

Answer (score 0):

Use the [JavaScript Console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to detect errors in your JavaScript.

This would have flagged that `getElementByID` is a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

Browser Console itself tells that there is error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID'
```

Replace `getElementByID` with `getElementById`.

```
function show() {
        var text = document.getElementById('textOff');
        console.log(text); //debugging
        text.id = 'mainText';
    };
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/fh6NG/